# How to retrieve data from json string in jsp send from the another page using ajax

Tags: html, json, jsp

I am developing a web application. I have get the value from the data base using jsp and displayed to the user. On certain action from the user, i want to load the another page which will require same values which are fetched from the database.

For this I have created json object of this data in page1.jsp and passed to the another page2.jsp.
Now I want to retrieve that data. I have tried with gunction getString() functions, but it gives null value.

my first page is which sends the json data

```
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url:   "./ProfileUser.jsp",            // This not redirecting. 
   data:  "jsonData=" + JSON.stringify(jsonobj),
   dataType: "json" 
   });
 $(location).attr('href',url);           //This is redirecting, If I removed this then another page is NOT loading
```

and the jsp code where I am retrieving this data

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="com.google.gson.JsonObject" %>
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject"%>
<%
String jsonData = request.getParameter("jsonData");
JSONObject j  =new JSONObject(jsonData);
String mobile = j.getAttribute("mobile");   //error occures here
%>
```

And i get error

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /ProfileUser.jsp at line 15

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /ProfileUser.jsp at line 15

12: <%
13: String jsonData = request.getParameter("jsonData");
14: //JONObject userinfo = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonData).nextValue();
15: JSONObject j  =new JSONObject(jsonData);
16: String mobile = j.getString("mobile");
17: %>
18: <!DOCTYPE html>


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.more(JSONTokener.java:89)
        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.next(JSONTokener.java:99)
        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.nextClean(JSONTokener.java:153)
        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:168)
        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:266)
        org.apache.jsp.ProfileUser_jsp._jspService(ProfileUser_jsp.java:75)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

How can get this data in jsp?
Thank you.